# Get Correct Client IP Address with .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Hello guys I got a requirement from my client asking me to pass the client IP Address to an antifraud API.
I'm working with.Net Core and C# on web development and I'm getting the client IP Address just like this:

```
HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.MapToIPv4().ToString();
```

The problem is that they are telling me that I'm passing a local IP Address instead of the Client IP.

Is there another way to get the correct IP that is requested?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Sounds like they should be using a proper firewall instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible you may not have added the `UseForwardedHeaders` middleware.

Add `UseForwardedHeaders` middleware to get the client `IP` address

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

Then:

```
string ip = _httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
```

Because when the application is run on `IIS`, `IIS` forward `HTTP` requests to the `Kestrel` and always you get local `IP` address instead of Client `IP`